# Fix Magento Delayed Emails Issue

Tags: php, magento, timezone

I've been using Magento for a couple of weeks and it seems to be working fine for what we need. The issue we're having now is that every time you complete an order the system sends the client and the store owner the invoice one hour later. For example, if the invoice is generated at 1:00pm the user and admin receives the invoice at 2:00pm. The idea is that the user and admin receive the invoice right away. We've configured Magento's Timezone to be in ours and also tried using other timezones but nothing.

Is there any way to fix this? Please have in mind that I'm just a designer with limited programming skills.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right direction. What did the trick was changing settings in System->Configuration->System->Cron Tab. The AOE_Scheduler was also pretty handy finding out the exact cron job.